# Is it possible to have a static list of Styles in Xaml

Tags: c#, list, xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like to have a static list of `Styles` in `Xaml`

So far I have tried:

```
<local:Styles xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Core;assembly=MyApp.Core">
  <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
  </Style>
</local:Styles>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class Styles : List<Style>
{
    public Styles()
    {
    }
}
```

but when I do

```
var styles = new Styles();
```

The class is empty.

As an aside I can't use `Application Resources` or `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: Are you looking for such kind of **ResourceDictionary** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your styles in a `ResourceDictionary` (Add -> New Item -> Resource Dictionary):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!-- Your styles here -->
    <Style ...

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Don't forget that you will need to add a reference to it in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="Your.App.Namespace"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Your.App.Namespace;component/Path/To/Dictionary.xaml"/>
            ...
```

To get hold of these styles in code-behind, you can use the `FindResource` method:

```
Style myStyle = App.Current.FindResource("MyStyleKey") as Style;
```

Comment: I'm using `Xamarin.Forms` so eventhough these are both valid methods I cant use `ResourceDictionary` (As for some reason Xamarin have `Sealed` the class. And I can't use `Application Resources` because I am using `MvvmCross` which doesn't provide application resources. Hence the need for a static list of styles

Comment: Hmm. You don't need to create a new C# class for `ResourceDictionary`, it's an item you need to add to your project. Right click on your project -> **Add** -> **New Item** -> **Resource Dictionary**. There is no C# code-behind for a resource dictionary. As for `Application Resources`, are you not able to simply edit the `App.xaml` file and add the `Application.Resources` element?

Comment: I can't find `ResourceDictionary` as an item to add only `Resource File` (I am building a PCL). I am not able to use Application. Resources because I am using MvvmCross where the base class is `MvxApplication` which doesn't inherit from `Application`. basically I dont have an App.xaml. I got around the issue in the end by saving the resources to a pages resources and loaded it into Application.Current.Resources in code behind

Answer (score 1):

One additional Idea that comes to mind

Create a standard Xamarin.Forms.Solution
Mark up the Application XAML with your Styles
Instantiate it and Serialize the Application.Resource to XML
Go back to your MVVMCross app and deserialize it on load and assign it to each page at construction or Application.Current.Resources. Once you have the format for the XML you'd be able to edit it directly and it would be portable from project to project basically a css style sheet(in xml format) for Xamarin Forms might be fun.